# Hidding Servers Filesystem in Gatsby / ReactJS?

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, security, gatsby

I am about to learn ReactJS.
I want to hide the filesystem structure of my server and only show the project root.
If i go to inspect tools in google-chrome i can see where my project is located on my C: Drive.
Wasnt able to find something about it and Ive got no Idea.

Hopefully, someone can help me.

[image]

Comment: It seems that you have some assets that are specified in HTML, CSS, and JS code by the full path on your disk. Make sure that you have no "C:\..." in any place in code and everything is served by a server that you use.

Comment: Gatsby seems to be able to read my whole filesystem. My Editor also recocnizes C: as my root path. Is there any option to set the gatsby-project root as root path?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using your computer as a server to serve your site so the inspect tools are able to recognize the origin of the code, assets, and images.

Locally, even using `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build` (and `gatsby serve`) you will always be able to see the root of your project, it happens with all web development files, not only in Gatsby.

In a real scenario, where it's a server (with a domain attached, not your PC) that serves the files you will never see the origin because your site will be placed in the `/public` or `/www` of your server. To prepare your project to be deployed, you should run `gatsby build` command, which will create a `/public` folder in the root of your project with your code compiled, that folder is the one that needs to be deployed.

Comment: Thanks. Now i know why it is called Serverless. ;)

Answer (score -1):

This is normal in development environment, for deploy your project try one of these approach in root of you project:

`npm build`

or

`yarn build`

This command build an optimized version of your project in `build` folder, after you can upload content of this folder to your `www/plulic` folder of your server,